# Winsock 10061/10060: Connection to remote server is not successful

Tags: c, winsock

There are some other questions related to this, but they are not solving my problem. So I am asking so that some other possible solution can be seen.
I am implementing the socket programming. Socket is being successfully created, and it connects successfully to localhost. But when I choose some remote server, then it gives the  error 10061 and sometimes 10060. I tried many remote servers(for example: google.com and my company hostname also).

I checked the firewall it is OFF. my code is given below:

```
/*
Socket Programming on Windows Machine
Author  : Raza Javed
Date    : 11-10-2022

*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

    // Winsock Initialization
    WSADATA wsa; // WSADATA is the structure that holds the information about Winsock library
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    struct hostent *he;
    char *hostname = "localhost";
    char ip[100];
    printf("Initializing Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa)!=0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError()); //WSAGetLastError is used to get more information about what error occured.
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialized.\n");

    // Socket Creation
    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create the socket: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    printf("Socket Created.\n");

    // Getting IP using "gethostbyname"
    if ((he = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("gethostbyname failed : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    addr_list = (struct in_addr **)he -> h_addr_list; // Casting h_addr_list to in_addr
    for(int i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
    }
    printf("%s resolved to %s\n", hostname, ip);

    // Connecting to server
    //memset(&server, "\0", sizeof(server));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(49835);

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("connect error : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }
    puts("connected");

    
    getchar(); // To hold the terminal screen
    return 0;
}
```

Listening port can be seen here:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49835        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

In case of localhost, I get the following output:

```
Initializing Winsock...Initialized.
Socket Created.
localhost resolved to 127.0.0.1
connected
```

But when I change it to some remote server for example google like below:

```
char *hostname = "www.google.com";
```

Then the output is:

```
Initializing Winsock...Initialized.
Socket Created.
www.google.com resolved to 142.251.209.132
connect error : 10060
```

Can someone please help in this. I am completely not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. maybe it would be helpful for someone else.

The mistake I was doing is that I have been always using the 'wrong port' to connect. To connect to remote server for example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), the port number will be 80, so the line of the code above will be:

```
server.sin_port = htons(80);
```

because it is for HTTP connection.

just by changing the line like above. It is connected now. Results below:

```
Initializing Winsock...Initialized.
Socket Created.
www.google.com resolved to 142.250.186.100
connected
```